# On embedding $\mathbb C[x_1,...,x_d]/P $ inside $\mathbb C[[T]]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, affine-varieties, formal-power-series, cohen-macaulay, projective-varieties

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $\mathbb C[x_1,...,x_d]$ such that ht$(P)=d-1$ i.e. $\dim (\mathbb C[x_1,...,x_d]/P)=1$.

Then is it necessarily true that there exists an injective $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism $\mathbb C[x_1,...,x_d]/P\to \mathbb C[[T]]$ ? If this is not true in general, would it be true if I moreover assumed $P$ is a homogeneous prime ideal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prime ideal $P$ corresponds to a curve $X \subseteq \Bbb P^d_{\Bbb C}$, so that the ring $\Bbb C[x_1, \dotsc, x_d]/P$ is just the coordinate ring $\Bbb C[X]$.

If you choose any smooth $\Bbb C$-point $x$ on $X$ (which exists, because the set of smooth points are Zariski dense), then the local ring $\Bbb C[X]_x$ has formal completion isomorphic to $\Bbb C[[T]]$. This gives an embedding $\Bbb C[X] \rightarrow \Bbb C[[T]]$.

One intuitive way of seeing this is to choose a local coordinate $T$ at the smooth point $x$, so that any rational function $f \in \Bbb C[X]$ can be viewed as an analytic function defined on an open neighborhood (in the usual analytic topology) of $T = 0$ in $\Bbb C$, and hence has a Taylor expansion (i.e. Laurent expansion without negative terms). Two analytic functions having the same Taylor expansion must be identical on the open neighborhood, and hence identical on the whole $X$, by irreducibility.

Comment: Sorry, my notations are a bit chaotic. By $\Bbb C [X]$ I meant the coordinate ring of the curve, but obviously I got confused with $C$ and $X$. Will correct it now.

Comment: A few questions: when you write $\mathbb C[X]_x$ you do mean localisation at the maximal ideal corresponding to $x$ , right ? Now I can't see why the completion of $\mathbb C[X]_x$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[[T]]$ ... first of all since completion and localisation, w.r.t. a maximal ideal , commute so the completion of $\mathbb C[X]_x$ (w.r.t. the maximal ideal of the point $x$) is just the completion of $\mathbb C[X]$ which is $\widehat {\mathbb C[x_1,...,x_n]}/\hat P$ and I don't see how this embeds into $\mathbb C[[T]]$ ... could you please clarify ?

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb C[X]_x$ is the localisation. The completion means the inverse limit $R=\lim_r \Bbb C[X]/m_x^r$, where $m_x$ is the maximal ideal of $\Bbb C[X]$ corresponding to $x$. This is a one dimensional complete regular local ring over (and containing) $\Bbb C$, which is algebraically closed, so $R$ must be isomorphic to $\Bbb C[[T]]$: choose any uniformizer $\pi\in R$ and define a map $\phi:\Bbb C[[T]]\rightarrow R$ sending $T$ to $\pi$. It's an easy exercise to show that $\phi$ is well-defined and is an isomorphism.